# whenever i try to install anything via ppa method,it displays this error at the end.what should i do?

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

whenever i try to install anything via ppa method,it displays this error at the end.what should i do?

```
download failed >
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--c
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned er
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please show the command used and try updating first `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

when ever you run apt it tries to finish the incomplete install.
judging from the error, something is wrong with the postscript of the package oracle-java7-installer.

do `apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer` and the messages will stop.
then you can try to reinstall it or java8 later.